# Dictionary<string, MyClass> to List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> where the Value in KeyValuePair is MyClass.ToString()

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();

//where MyClass has an override for ToString()
```

Now how do I get a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` from dict where the Value in KeyValuePair if `MyClass.ToString()` and the Key in the KeyValuePair is same as that of dict..?

Is there an easy way to do that? How can I use the `IDictionary.ToList<>()` function there? Plz enlighten ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not tested/compiled, but something like that should work:

```
dict.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())).ToList()
```

if the syntax is not 100% spot on, I hope you got the idea.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot Jods.. works perfect with
dict.Select(kvp => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString())).ToList()

Comment: I'm new to using LINQ and the lambda operator. What does "=>" here mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use LINQ:

```
var list = dict.Select(k => 
  new KeyValuePair<string,string>(k.Key, k.Value.ToString()))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for the answer. It might seem pretty straight forward to you, but can you plz explain what the lambda operator: "=>" here means?

Comment: The parameter to `.Select()` is a function, so the `k => ...` defines a function that takes `k` as a parameter and the body of the function is after the `=>`.

Comment: Got it.. Plz correct me if I'm wrong..
The syntax: k => lambda(k) there meant that lambda(k), the anonymous function.. used in place like a javascript inline-code block.

( k => lambda(k) ) will substitute for a delegate.

Comment: Yes, you could have used some other function which takes a dictionary key-pair and use that as your parameter instead of the lambda function.